# Text doesn't go under the image

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to wrap a text around the image. The image is on the left side and text in the right.

I'm using bootstrap latest version and both sides are col-3 and col-9. Why the text doesn't go below the image when it is longer than the image and why the image seems to take whole height of the page?

This is how my code looks like

```
<div class="row intext">
      <div class="col-sm-3 img-hover">
        <figure class="figure">
          <p class="lead fw-bold text-center">"TTTTTTTTTTT"</p>
          <p style="text-align: center;">Some text</p>
          <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/400" class="card-img-top" alt="">
          <figcaption>Copyright</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Click to Learn More</a></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-9">
        <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
        ... more text
      </div>
    </div>
```

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ymbnx7w6/1/

Comment: why text will  go under image? You set col-3 for image and col-9 for text so it's working according to it.

Comment: Well, I'm following this code and here is goes under the image: https://codepen.io/davdenic/pen/bPGRqa

Comment: https://codepen.io/davdenic/pen/bPGRqa this code I tried to copy and check but it's not working how it's showing in pen.

Comment: Am not sure either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this instead of row, column just use float-start class of bootstrap I just removed your col-9, row and add float-start  instead of col-3

```css
.intext {
  margin: 15px 0;
}

.intext figure {
  margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
}

.intext figure figcaption {
  font-size: small;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.intext h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
   integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="intext">
   <div class="img-hover float-start">
  <figure class="figure">
     <p class="lead fw-bold text-center">"TTTTTTTTTTT"</p>
     <p style="text-align: center;">Some text</p>
     <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/400" class="card-img-top img-fluid" alt="">
     <figcaption>Copyright</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Click to Learn More</a></p>
   </div>
   <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
   </p>
   <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
   </p>
   <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
   </p>
   <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
   </p>
   <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
   </p>
   <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem
  Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem 
   </p>
</div>
enter code here
```

Comment: Yes, this should do the "trick". Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your image just needs a float value - in this case "float: left;" so the text knows how to deal with the image. This deals with the image only, not sure what you want to do wit the "copyright" area.

```
 <!-- CSS -->
 .intext {
 margin: 15px 0;
 }
 .intext figure {
 margin: 0 15px 15px 0;
 }
 .intext figure figcaption {
 font-size: small;
 color: white;
 background: black;
 padding: 5px;
 }
 .intext h2 {
 margin-top: 0;
 }

.card-img-top {
float: left;
margin: 0 20px 20px 0;
}

<!-- HTML -->
<div class="row intext">
  <div class="col-sm-3 img-hover">
    <figure class="figure">
      <p class="lead fw-bold text-center">"TTTTTTTTTTT"</p>
      <p style="text-align: center;">Some text</p>
      <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/600/400" class="card-img-top" alt="">
      <figcaption>Copyright</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="" class="btn btn-primary">Click to Learn More</a></p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9">
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem           Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
    <p>Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem Lorem </p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/akv34wus/1/